# Targeting dom element with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise

I am using a JS Promise to asynchronously get the user's location inside `getLocation()`. And then I'm making an Ajax request to the server inside `postLocation()`.

```
$('#add_location_btn').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#code').val().length === 0) {
            window.alert('Enter a valid code!');
        } else {
            getLocation().then(function (pos) {
                $('#addlocation_loader').attr('hidden', false);  // Show loading sign
                return pos;
            }).then(function (pos) {
                postLocation(pos);
            });
        }
        $('#addlocation_loader').attr('hidden', true);  // Hide loading sign
    });
```

However, eventually changing `addlocation_loader` 'hidden' attribute to true is not working, meaning that the attribute is properly set to false but never turns true.

**Edit**

It's worth noting that I want to hide the loading sign after `postLocation()` is executed.

I have tried setting 'hidden' to true in a third `then()` statement, but the sign now never shows up. It seems that the show and hide statements are quickly executed after one another, which is confusing (When I comment out the hide statement the sign is normally shown, which means that both execute).

```
getLocation().then(function (pos) {
    $('#addlocation_loader').attr('hidden', false);  // Show loading sign
    return pos;
}).then(function (pos) {
    postLocation(pos);
}).then(function () {
    $('#addlocation_loader').attr('hidden', true);  // Hide loading sign
});
```

Comment: shouldn't that final line be in another `.then()` chaining off the `postLocation` promise? As it is, it happens synchronously as soon as the button clicks, so it's *first* getting hidden, then shown once `getLocation` has finished - and never gets hidden again. [Or am I missing something?]

Comment: You may have your hide/show loader backwards. Looks Like you set `hidden` to `false` when the location is returned and to `true` when the button is pressed.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've tried doing exactly this, but it didn't quite work. I have added more info about this in the question details.

Comment: The trick is to do `return postLocation(pos)` instead of `postLocation(pos)`. By returning you are passing the promise to the next `.then()`, otherwise the next `.then()` will resolve immediately because you returned void/undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the loader, you should do it within the `.then()` callback, because that is when the promise has been resolved. So what you want to do is:

1. Show loader before executing `postLocation()`
2. Remember to return the promise from `postLocation()` (which you didn't do in the code)
3. Hide the loader when the promise is resolved (after posting the position has succeeded)

Here is your fixed code:

```
// Perform async operation
getLocation().then(function (pos) {

    // Show loader
    $('#addlocation_loader').attr('hidden', false);

    // Post location. Remember to return the promise to chain it!
    return postLocation(pos);

}).then(function() {

    // Hide loader when position is successfully posted
    $('#addlocation_loader').attr('hidden', true);  

});
```

Comment: you mean `prop` and not `attr`

Comment: @Alen.Toma I have no idea what that attribute is doing, it is probably not a boolean attribute. However without looking at OP's full code, it would be spurious to try to change it to `prop` just because one suspect it's a boolean attribute/prop.

Comment: yeh but he had a comment that says `// Hide loading sign` so i suppose that hes trying to hide the loader. Could also use `hide` and `show`. but i may be wrong to

Comment: Alternating the 'hidden' attribute resembles showing/hiding the element.

@Terry I am actually trying to show the element after ```getLocation()``` is executed and hiding it after ```postLocation()``` finishes, I've added more info about this in the question details.

Comment: @Ahmad `getLocation()` is executed immediately, so you can just show the loader right before that. When `getLocation()`'s promise is resolved, you then call `postLocation()`. The reason why your code appears to execute immediately is because you did not return the promise, i.e. `return postLocation(pos)`. This means the next `.then()` is immediately resolved ;) see my updated answer.

Comment: @Terry The thing is, ```getLocation()``` waits input from user, so I only want to show the loading sign after ```getLocation()``` is executed.

Comment: @Ahmad Alright. If that's the case, toggle the hidden attribute in the first `.then()`. It turns out the only issue why your original code doesn't work is because you didn't return `postLocation()`. See my updated answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Terry I tried doing that, but it unfortunately got me to the initial problem which is the sign not being show at all. It also seems (when I stop the statement hiding the sign) that the sign is shown almost at the same time when ```postLocation()``` finishes, which is even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an asynchronous function to the attribute to false. That means that probably

```
$('#addlocation_loader').attr('hidden', true);
```

is executed before

```
$('#addlocation_loader').attr('hidden', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have your hide/show loader backwards. Looks Like you set hidden to false when the location is returned and to true when the button is pressed.

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
$("#add_location_btn").on("click", function() {
  const $loader = $("#addlocation_loader");
  if ($("#code").val().length === 0) {
    window.alert("Enter a valid code!");
  } else {
    $loader.attr("hidden", false); // Show when requested
    getLocation()
      .then(function(pos) {
        $loader.attr("hidden", true); // Hide when returned
        postLocation(pos);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I actually want to show the sign after getting the location and hide it after ```postLocation()``` finishes execution.